# How to test the internet connection behind a proxy?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, vbscript, proxy, cmd

I have this vbscript that works well on **Windows 7 32-bit without proxy**

In order to improve it, I seek for this solution: **How to test internet connection behind a proxy ?**
The solution perhaps it will be in **VBScript or Powershell or Batch**, much as I find a way to check whether i am connected or not behind a proxy !

**The piece of code to improve it when i'm behind a proxy**

If there is a trick to check if i'm connected to internet when i'm behind a proxy this is my question ?

```
If CheckConnection = true then
    Msgbox "i'm connected to internet",vbinformation+vbSystemModal,"Check connection to internet"
Else
    Msgbox "i'm not connected to internet",vbCritical+vbSystemModal,"Check connection to internet"
End if
'***************************************************************************
Function CheckConnection()
    CheckConnection = False
        strComputer = "smtp.gmail.com"
        Set objPing = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\").ExecQuery _
        ("select * from Win32_PingStatus where address = '" & strComputer & "'")
        For Each objStatus in objPing
            If objStatus.Statuscode = 0 Then
                MyLoop = False
                CheckConnection = True
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next
End Function
'******************************************************************************
```

**The hole code :**

```
Option Explicit
Dim Title,MyScriptPath,DJBuzzRadio,MyLoop,strComputer,objPing,objStatus,FSO,FolderScript,URLICON,Icon
Title = "Radio DJ Buzz Live by © Hackoo © 2015"
MyScriptPath = WScript.ScriptFullName
Set FSO = Createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
FolderScript = FSO.GetParentFolderName(MyScriptPath) 'Chemin du dossier ou se localise le Vbscript
Icon = FolderScript & "\akg.ico"
URLICON = ChrW(104)&ChrW(116)&ChrW(116)&ChrW(112)&ChrW(58)&ChrW(47)&ChrW(47)&ChrW(104)&ChrW(97)&ChrW(99)&ChrW(107)&ChrW(111)&ChrW(111)&ChrW(46)&ChrW(97)&ChrW(108)&ChrW(119)&ChrW(97)&ChrW(121)&ChrW(115)&ChrW(100)&ChrW(97)&ChrW(116)&ChrW(97)&ChrW(46)&ChrW(110)&ChrW(101)&ChrW(116)&ChrW(47)&ChrW(97)&ChrW(107)&ChrW(103)&ChrW(46)&ChrW(105)&ChrW(99)&ChrW(111)
If Not FSO.FileExists(Icon) Then Call Download(URLICON,Icon)
DJBuzzRadio = ChrW(104)&ChrW(116)&ChrW(116)&ChrW(112)&ChrW(58)&ChrW(47)&ChrW(47)&ChrW(119)&ChrW(119)&ChrW(119)&ChrW(46)&ChrW(99)&ChrW(104)&ChrW(111)&ChrW(99)&ChrW(114)&ChrW(97)&ChrW(100)&ChrW(105)&ChrW(111)&ChrW(115)&ChrW(46)&ChrW(99)&ChrW(104)&ChrW(47)&ChrW(100)&ChrW(106)&ChrW(98)&ChrW(117)&ChrW(122)&ChrW(122)&ChrW(114)&ChrW(97)&ChrW(100)&ChrW(105)&ChrW(111)&ChrW(95)&ChrW(119)&ChrW(105)&ChrW(110)&ChrW(100)&ChrW(111)&ChrW(119)&ChrW(115)&ChrW(46)&ChrW(109)&ChrW(112)&ChrW(51)&ChrW(46)&ChrW(97)&ChrW(115)&ChrW(120)
Call Shortcut(MyScriptPath,"DJ Buzz Radio")
MyLoop = True
If CheckConnection = True Then Call AskQuestion()
'***************************************************************************
Function CheckConnection()
    CheckConnection = False
    While MyLoop = True
        strComputer = "smtp.gmail.com"
        Set objPing = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\").ExecQuery _
        ("select * from Win32_PingStatus where address = '" & strComputer & "'")
        For Each objStatus in objPing
            If objStatus.Statuscode = 0 Then
                MyLoop = False
                CheckConnection = True
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next
        Pause(10) 'To sleep for 10 secondes
    Wend
End Function
'***************************************************************************
Sub Play(URL)
    Dim Sound
    Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX")               
    Sound.URL = URL
    Sound.settings.volume = 100                               
    Sound.Controls.play                                     
    do while Sound.currentmedia.duration = 0                
        wscript.sleep 100                                       
    loop                                                    
    wscript.sleep (int(Sound.currentmedia.duration)+1)*1000 
End Sub
'***************************************************************************
Sub Shortcut(CheminApplication,Nom)
    Dim objShell,fso,DesktopPath,objShortCut,MyTab,strCurDir
    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    strCurDir = fso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
    MyTab = Split(CheminApplication,"\")
    If Nom = "" Then
        Nom = MyTab(UBound(MyTab))
    End if
    DesktopPath = objShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
    Set objShortCut = objShell.CreateShortcut(DesktopPath & "\" & Nom & ".lnk")
    objShortCut.TargetPath = Dblquote(CheminApplication)
    ObjShortCut.IconLocation = strCurDir & "\akg.ico"
    objShortCut.Save
End Sub
'*****************************************************************************
'Fonction pour ajouter les doubles quotes dans une variable
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'*****************************************************************************
Function AppPrevInstance()   
    With GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")   
        With .ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE CommandLine LIKE " & CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptFullName) & _
            " AND CommandLine LIKE '%WScript%' OR CommandLine LIKE '%cscript%'")   
            AppPrevInstance = (.Count > 1)   
        End With   
    End With   
End Function    
'******************************************************************************
Function CommandLineLike(ProcessPath)   
    ProcessPath = Replace(ProcessPath, "\", "\\")   
    CommandLineLike = "'%" & ProcessPath & "%'"   
End Function
'******************************************************************************
Sub Pause(NSeconds)
    Wscript.Sleep(NSeconds*1000)
End Sub
'******************************************************************************
Sub AskQuestion()
    Dim Question,MsgAR,MsgFR,MsgEN
    MsgFR = "Voulez-vous écouter DJ Buzz Radio en direct ?" & vbcr & "Oui = Pour écouter" & vbcr & "Non = Pour arrêter" & vbcr & String(50,"*")
    MsgEN = "Did you want to listen to the Radio DJ Buzz Live ?" & vbcr & "Yes = To listen" & vbcr & "No = To stop" & vbcr & String(50,"*")
    MsgAR = ChrW(1607)&ChrW(1604)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(1578)&ChrW(1585)&ChrW(1610)&ChrW(1583)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(1571)&ChrW(1606)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(1578)&ChrW(1587)&ChrW(1605)&ChrW(1593)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(1604)&ChrW(1575)&ChrW(1610)&ChrW(1601)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(1585)&ChrW(1575)&ChrW(1583)&ChrW(1610)&ChrW(1608)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(68)&ChrW(74)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(66)&ChrW(117)&ChrW(122)&ChrW(122)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(82)&ChrW(97)&ChrW(100)&ChrW(105)&ChrW(111)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(63) & vbcr & ChrW(1606)&ChrW(1593)&ChrW(1605)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(61)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(1604)&ChrW(1575)&ChrW(1587)&ChrW(1578)&ChrW(1605)&ChrW(1575)&ChrW(1593) & vbcr & ChrW(1604)&ChrW(1575)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(61)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(1604)&ChrW(1608)&ChrW(1602)&ChrW(1601) & vbcr &_
    String(50,"*")
    Question = MsgBox(MsgFR & vbcr & MsgEN & vbcr & MsgAR,vbYesNO+vbQuestion+vbSystemModal,Title)
    If Question = VbYes And Not AppPrevInstance() Then
        Call Play(DJBuzzRadio)
    End If
    If Question = VbYes And AppPrevInstance() Then 
        MsgBox "There is another instance in execution !" & VbCrLF &_
        "Il y a une autre instance en cours d'exécution !"& VbcrLF &_
        ChrW(1607)&ChrW(1606)&ChrW(1575)&ChrW(1603)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(1605)&ChrW(1579)&ChrW(1575)&ChrW(1604)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(1570)&ChrW(1582)&ChrW(1585)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(1601)&ChrW(1610)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(1575)&ChrW(1604)&ChrW(1578)&ChrW(1606)&ChrW(1601)&ChrW(1610)&ChrW(1584)& VbcrLF &_
        CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptName),VbExclamation+vbSystemModal,Title    
        WScript.Quit()
    End If
    If Question = VbNo And Not AppPrevInstance() Then
        Call Kill("wscript.exe")
    End If
    If Question = VbNo And AppPrevInstance() Then
        Call Kill("wscript.exe")
    End If
End Sub
'******************************************************************************
Sub Kill(MyProcess)
    Dim Titre,colItems,objItem,Processus,Question
    Titre = " Processus "& DblQuote(MyProcess) &" en cours d'exécution "
    Set colItems = GetObject("winmgmts:").ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process " _
    & "Where Name like '%"& MyProcess &"%' AND commandline like " & CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptFullName) & "",,48)
    For Each objItem in colItems
        objItem.Terminate(0)' Tuer ce processus
    Next
End Sub
'******************************************************************************
Sub Download(strFileURL,strHDLocation)
    Dim objXMLHTTP,objADOStream
    Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    objXMLHTTP.open "GET", strFileURL, false
    objXMLHTTP.send()
    If objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
        Set objADOStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        objADOStream.Open
        objADOStream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary
        objADOStream.Write objXMLHTTP.ResponseBody
        objADOStream.Position = 0    'Set the stream position to the start
        objADOStream.SaveToFile strHDLocation,2
        objADOStream.Close
        Set objADOStream = Nothing
    End If
    Set objXMLHTTP = Nothing 
    Shortcut MyScriptPath,"DJ Buzz Radio"
    MsgBox "Un raccourci a été crée sur votre bureau !"& vbcr &_
    "A shortcut was created on your desktop !"& vbcr &_
    ChrW(1578)&ChrW(1605)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(1573)&ChrW(1606)&ChrW(1588)&ChrW(1575)&ChrW(1569)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(1575)&ChrW(1582)&ChrW(1578)&ChrW(1589)&ChrW(1575)&ChrW(1585)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(1593)&ChrW(1604)&ChrW(1609)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(1587)&ChrW(1591)&ChrW(1581)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(1575)&ChrW(1604)&ChrW(1605)&ChrW(1603)&ChrW(1578)&ChrW(1576),vbSystemModal+vbInformation,Title
End Sub
'**************************************************************************
```

Comment: I don't know why you downvote this question ? at least you must leave a comment to explain your downvote ??

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I'm getting a "write my code for me" vibe from this question (even though I know you're not the kind of person who asks "write my code for me" questions).

Comment: @SomethingDark ok :) my purpose is just to improve my code because i write and i tested only on windows 7;  and i share all my code; so i will edit it to focus on the piece where i want to improve it :)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the settings of the local computer you can query the registry:

```
REG QUERY "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v  ProxyEnable
```

If the value is 0x1 then the there is set proxy. You can check also the proxy value through the value of `ProxyServer` at the same location. More info [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/819961?wa=wsignin1.0).

You can check if your external IP is the same like your internal IP address.
This uses [winhttpjs.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/winhttpjs.bat)

```
for /f "skip=1 tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('winhhttpjs.bat "http://www.telize.com/ip" -saveTo con') do (
    set "ip=%%a"
)
ipconfig| find "%ip%" || (
  echo not real IP/proxy
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion; but you can check my edit to understand what is my real purpose ;)

Comment: Very nice hybride (JS/Batch) indeed ;)